# How to select COUNT of one table column where there are no matches in another table column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two MySQL tables that are relational based on an ID number. I need to select the count of the IDs in the first table that do NOT match any ID in the second table. This is what I tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ask_questions.id)) 
FROM ask_questions 
INNER JOIN ask_answers ON ask_questions.id != ask_answers.question_id;
```

I thought that using the "!=" would return results that do not match but the number returned is not correct. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `LEFT JOIN` since you want to get `ID` that do not have atleast a match on the other table.

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT(ask_questions.id)) 
FROM    ask_questions 
        LEFT JOIN ask_answers 
            ON ask_questions.id = ask_answers.question_id
WHERE   ask_answers.question_id IS NULL
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

An alternative with `JOIN` is by using `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT(id)) 
FROM    ask_questions 
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  null
            FROM    ask_answers
            WHERE   ask_questions.id = ask_answers.question_id
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT IN`

```
SELECT COUNT(ask_questions.id)
FROM ask_questions
WHERE ask_questions.id NOT IN(SELECT question_id FROM ask_answers)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ask_questions.id)) 
FROM ask_questions 
LEFT JOIN ask_answers ON ask_questions.id = ask_answers.question_id;
WHERE ask_answers.question_id IS NULL
```

The left join will let you get the `ask_questions` even when they don't have `ask_answers`.

The ones that don't have `ask_answers` will have the id `null`

Answer (score 0):

Use except:

```
select count(*) from 
    (select id from questions 
     except 
     select id from ask_answers_questions) as subtable;
```

EXCEPT will remove duplicates for you.

--dmg

Answer (score 0):

You want to outer join the tables, not inner join them, and select the columns in the second table that are null.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ask_questions.id))
FROM ask_questions
    LEFT JOIN ask_answers ON ask_questions.id = ask_answers.question_id
WHERE ISNULL(ask_answers.id)
```